# Recursive DirFiles to build MSI using Wix#

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, wixsharp

I'm exploring the features of Wix# and I'm stunned with it's simplicity in comparison to Wix. We are already using the QT Installer Framework, but our customers are also in need for a MSI installation package.

I already have a directory containing all files for our product and there is simply one package. I tried to include all files in `C:\Temp\MyProductFiles` into my MSI installer.

```
using System;
using WixSharp;

class Script
{
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Compiler.WixLocation= @"C:\WiX-3.7\binaries"; 
        var project = new Project("MyProduct",
                          new Dir(@"C:\Temp\MyProduct", 
                            new DirFiles(@"C:\Temp\MyProductFiles\*.*")
                           )
                      );
        project.UI = WUI.WixUI_Common;

        Compiler.BuildMsi(project);
    }
}
```

The installer basically worked as expected, but unfortunately `C:\Temp\MyProductFiles` contains many subdirectories, that I don't want state explicitly every time, as we have several products.

Is there an easy way to automatically include all files and subdirectories using Wix#?

Maybe one can do it also using C#, but I'm not proficient in C# and I really don't know how to start.

Comment: If you just want an easier WiX experience take a look at: https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no in-built mechanism to take all the sub directories, but you can just recursively traverse the tree, and project each entry into `DirFiles`

```
IEnumerable<string> GetSubdirectories(string root)
{
    string[] subdirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(root);
    foreach (var subdirectory in subdirectories)
    {
        yield return subdirectory;
        foreach (var nestedDirectory in GetSubdirectories(subdirectory))
        {
            yield return nestedDirectory;
        }
    }
}
```

Projection can output into an array of `DirFiles` with mandatory wild-card pattern:

```
DirFiles[] dirFiles = GetSubdirectories(rootPath).Select(d => new DirFiles(Path.Combine(d, "*.*"))).ToArray();
```

Then, it's just matter of passing it:

```
var project = new Project("MyProduct", new Dir(@"C:\Temp\MyProduct", dirFiles)));
```

Comment: Many thanks. After adding the appropriate `using` directives it works.

Answer (score 4):

To include all files and subdirectories, use `new Files("@"C:\Temp\MyProductFiles\*.*")` instead of `new DirFiles(@"C:\Temp\MyProductFiles\*.*"`.

```csharp
var project =
    new Project("MyProduct",
        new Dir(@"%ProgramFiles%\My Company\My Product",
            new Files(@"..\Release Folder\Release\*.*")
```

See ["Release Folder" WixSharp Sample](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp/blob/c8783ba1448f2a592ef0d1710d11be93ce841b23/Source/src/WixSharp.Samples/Wix%23%20Samples/Release%20Folder/setup.cs)

This question was also addressed in [Issue #439 - List directories with wilcards and nested DirFiles](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp/issues/439)